# Change value of var with jquery radio button live on page

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Guys what I want to do is very simple. I've a script. What it does is when we write Hello in the box bellow, it, live on the page shows the images of "H E L L O" which makes sound Hello. I want to provide 3-4 versions of it. So I'm willing to use radio button for that. I.e Radio button 1 = Style 1, radio button 2 = style 2.. So how can I do that on live page to let the jquery check whenever visitor change the radio button check and click on the next button then there should be next style, without refreshing page. As the images below in output shows images without being refreshed. I'm using this.

```
$(".from textarea").live("keyup", function update() {
  var str = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  str = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(letter) {
    return Letters2[letter] + ' ';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

once you set up the group of radio buttons like so

```
<input name="style" value="style-1"/> style 1
<input name="style" value="style-2"/> style 2
```

Then you can bind the buttons to the change event. You can do it with live if you want to.

```
$("input[name=style]").live("change",function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        var selectValue = $(this).val();
        // remove old images, and place the new ones. 
    }
});
```

This should give you the functionality you need.